# Infinitely many non-constant holomorphic maps to hyperbolic Riemann surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $M$ be a closed complex manifold and let $S$ be a closed hyperbolic Riemann surface.

Can there be infinitely many non-constant holomorphic maps $M\to S$? Can there be uncountably many?

Comment: Yes but the answer is deceiving, for example $\mathbb P^1 \times S$ has this property.

Comment: The set of non-constant (hence surjective) morphisms $M\to S$ is finite. I can write a bit more about this later. For now, have a look at Kobayashi's book "Hyperbolic Complex Spaces". You can also have a look at https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.11981 (especially the sections on "bounded varieties" and the later section on finiteness of Sur(Y,X)).

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet  A dominant morphism from $\mathbb{P}^1\times S\to S$ has to contract each $\mathbb{P}^1\times \{s\}$ and therefore factors over a (dominant) morphism $S\to S$, and there are only finitely many of those.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar oh you are right, I made a stupid mistake. Thank for your comment !